# Run Jupyter cells in slideshow mode

Tags: slideshow, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

You can display a Jupyter notebook in an active html setting by running :

```
$ jupyter nbconvert untitled.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

Is there any ways to run a notebook in the same slideshow format in order to allow for a live presentation/execution of your cells ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check out the Jupyter plugin RISE using Reveal.JS:

- Github Repo: https://github.com/damianavila/RISE
- Documentation: https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/maint-5.5/

It's awesome.

Comment: Thanx it is exactly what I was looking for (although it is not working that well on my computer).

Comment: my guess he hasn't accepted it is probably because it is not working that well on his computer.

Comment: Better late than never, I accepted the answer (sorry for the delay ;-) ).

I did a presentation (running code while presenting) with RISE several weeks ago, it worked quite well !