# Interactive Jupyter/IPython notebooks in slideshow mode?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to run Jupyter Notebooks in an interactive slideshow mode? That is, Python kernel would be running in the background and I can modify and execute cells.

The following command generates HTML slideshow and I can't modify nor execute the cells:

```
jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

Comment: https://github.com/damianavila/RISE

Comment: Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667931/run-jupyter-cells-in-slideshow-mode

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update #2:** The version of RISE on PyPI installed with `pip` no longer seems to work with modern Jupyter Notebooks. Instead, the README inside RISE's [repository](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE) recommends installing with this command, which at least in my case did result in a working slideshow:

```
conda install -c damianavila82 rise
```

**Original:** Yes! Install this by following its instructions:

https://github.com/damianavila/RISE

and then restart the Jupyter Notebook server and re-open one of your notebooks. There should now be an "Enter/Exit Live Reveal Slideshow" button on the notebook toolbar, just to the right of the "CellToolbar" button.

**Update #1:** Both `pip install rise` and `conda install rise` should now be able to successfully install it!

Comment: pip recently added!

Comment: the "Enter/Exit Live Reveal Slideshow" did not appear to me, and the "CellToolbar" disappeared !

Answer (score 1):

Another option is View=>Cell toolbar=>None.
When necessary, run

```
pip install rise
```

or

```
conda install rise
```

in terminal. And relaunch Jupyter notebook.